# python 3.3 converting sentences to positions

Tags: python

i need this set of code to be able to convert sentence/sentence2/sentence3 into there positions as a seperate list for each sentence, preferably in a simalar method to the one of which i have attempted.
so the out put should look something like:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 4]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 1, 11, 12, 13, 14, 8]

```
sentence = ("ask not what you can do for your country ask what your country can do for you")
sentence2 = ("some people enjoy computing others do not enjoy computing")
sentence3 = ("i will use this as my last sentence as i do not need another sentence")

d = {}
i = 0
values = []
for i, word in enumerate(sentence, sentence2, sentence3(" ")):
    if not word in d:
        d[word] = (i + 1)
    values += [d[word]]
print(values)
```

Comment: You will have to explain what position is. What you mean by multiple sentences and things like that. It already works on 3 sentences (but not on 1).

Comment: Are you sure that your code works in first place.

Comment: thank you for providing the expected output. Please see my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

This solves it

```
def conv2pos(*sentences):
    def conv_one(s):
        words = s.split()
        word_pos = {w:words.index(w) for w in set(words)}
        return [word_pos[w]+1 for w in words]

    return [conv_one(s) for s in sentences]

print(conv2pos(sentence, sentence2, sentence3))
```

as for the given sentences it produces

```
[
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 1, 11, 12, 13, 14, 8]
]
```

Basically, for every sentence provided, it splits the sentence into words (on whitespace).

Then it creates a dictionary that maps a word with its first position in the sentence for every unique word.

Then it creates a list of the position of each word in the sentence according to such dictionary.

Note: the dictionary is optional. It is used to cache the position of each word and avoid scanning the list for words which have been encountered already. In case we wanted to remove it we can do

```
def conv2pos(*sentences):
    def conv_one(s):
        words = s.split()
        return [words.index(w)+1 for w in words]

    return [conv_one(s) for s in sentences]
```